# How to configure Firebase Analytics using Firebase JS SDK to support Cross-Domain tracking working for Google Ad Conversion tracking

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, google-ads-api

Having a Website `www.example.com` and a WebApp `myapp.example.com` with the following configuration:

- Both the Website and the WebApp use the Firebase JS SDK for tracking analytics events using the same Firebase config (= they track in the same linked Web+App GA Property)
- The Website contains the landing page where people from Google Ads land
- The Website has a regular `<a ...>` link to the WebApp (`myapp.example.com`)
- Conversion events are set up in the WebApp for tracking
- The GA Property is correctly linked to Google Ads and Conversions are imported correctly in Google Ads

The user flow this issue is about is:
`Google Ad` -> Landing page on `www.example.com` -> navigates to `myapp.example.com` -> conversion on `myapp.example.com`

The situation is now that tracking works from both domains and conversions are also tracked in GA, meaning: if I view the "Conversions" Report, I see the conversions for these events. Also if I set the attribution selector for a specific event to "Google Ads preferred last click" [image: Google Ads Preferred last click option], I can see that some conversions are attributed to the Google Ads campaigns.

But Google Ads does not recognize these conversions and shows the message "No recently tracked conversions" for these events even after waiting several days.

When switching the Attribution model in GA to "Cross-channel last click" for the conversion, the medium `cpc` (as it is displayed with the attribution model "Google Ads preferred last click" applied) is replaced by `referral` and campaign information is no longer available.

So I guess this is where the conversion tracking for Google Ads breaks and that's the reason why Google Ads does not detect the conversions correctly: because they happen on the "referral" from `www.example.com` and not directly from the initial Google Ads referral - even though Google Analytics can attribute the conversions correctly when setting the attribution model as mentioned above.

For regular GA using analytics.js, as far as I know there is a specific setup possible using the options `{'allowLinker': true}` and `ga('linker:autoLink', ['example-2.com'] );` (as described in this [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342)).

But for Firebase JS SDK, I could not manage to find any information how to setup cross-domain (even though it's only about subdomains in this case) tracking correctly so Google Ads still attributes the conversions correctly to the domains.

What needs to be done with this setup so that conversion tracking in Google Ads works correctly with the given setup using Firebase JS SDK?

Comment: I am in exactly the same boat as you. Have two firebase web apps hosted on the same project. Conversions are track correctly on Analytics but as soon as we go over to Ads they just display `No recently tracked conversions`.

I have been in coms with the Ads team for the past two weeks and the solution they have provided so far was to ensure I am using the same `measurementId` (part of the firebase config) for both webapps. Doing this has still not solved my problem.

Have you managed to find any solutions yet?

Comment: @MatthewMullin unfortunately, I am still having this issue. I am also in contact with the Ads team but my case is still at the expert's team. Since this is taking too long for me to wait for the solution (if there is one at all), I decided to add a new conversion event when navigating from the website to the app and use this in Ads. This is far from ideal but at least I get some conversion information even though it does not reflect a real conversion.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did anyone found a solution for this ?